# JSON object returns 400 even though it looks right

Tags: c#, rest, blazor-webassembly, jira-rest-api

**Why does two POST calls with the same JSON return different responses?**

I am building a project in Blazor WASM and sending a POST request via HttpClient to the Jira API.

Creating a normal [comment](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-comments/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-comment-post)  without anything special included works fine, but when I want to add a [hardBreak](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/apis/document/nodes/hardBreak/#node---hardbreak) or anything else other than normal text, the POST returns 400.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Response Status Code: 400. Response Content: {“errorMessages”:[“INVALID_INPUT”],“errors”:{}}

I think my problem lies somewhere with the C# object

```cs
   public class Content
        {
            [JsonProperty("type")] 
            public string Type { get; set; } = "";
            [JsonProperty("text")] 
            public string? Text { get; set; }
        }
```

```cs
     public class Content
        {
            [JsonProperty("type")] 
            public string Type { get; set; } = "";
        }
        public class TextContent : Content
        {
            [JsonProperty("text")] 
            public string? Text { get; set; }
        }
```

both of these classes when serialized returns the same JSON (to my eyes atleast) but the bottom one is the only one working.

So why does only the bottom one work when the JSON itself looks?

this is the JSON, looks the same in both cases

```json
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {
        "content": [
          {
            "text": "Test",
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "type": "hardBreak"
          },
          {
            "text": "Test",
            "type": "text"
          }
        ],
        "type": "paragraph"
      }
    ],
    "type": "doc",
    "version": 1
  }
}
```

I've tried making the Text nullable and adding `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` to the **Text** property, but it did not make a difference. I've also tried changing the serialization options.

Comment: HTTP Request/Response is HTML format and has special characters.  The Request/Response has three parts 1) URI 2) Header(s) 3) Body. Contents is the body.  There is a Content-Type which can be text, json, and other formats.  Your first link has 'application/json'. Client can only send the type of data the server is expecting.  Not all servers will accept json unless programmed to accept json.  It is hard to say from info provided what is root issue.  Error 400 says server doesn't expect the type of data or the data is in the wrong format.

Comment: @jdweng The POST request has 'application/json' in the header. The problem is that the JSON in both cases looks the same and has the same headers, etc. The only difference is the C# class structure, but the final JSON that gets sent looks the same.

Comment: The client serializes a c# class and then the server deserializes the data back to the classes.  You need the same classes in client and server code.  The deserialize method will automatically convert back to the classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure the first class doesn't serialize a hard break as something like `{"type":"hardBreak","text":""}` or `{"type":"hardBreak","text":null}`? If it does then that may well be the cause as `text` doesn't seem to be a valid field on a `hardbreak` according to the API docs. It would help if you tell us what library you're using to serialize and any settings you're passing to it which would control how it handles things like null or empty property values.

Comment: Hello! and thanks, that thought had crossed my mind as well, but in both scenarios, the text field wasn't present. I've tried posting using both HttpClient and RestSharp with Json.net. Though I will say I'm pretty embarrassed now, I have a fond memory that I tried this, but by adding `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` as a setting when serializing, it seemed to have fixed the issue.... Thanks both @sbridewell and @jdweng

Comment: Happy to help :-) If you've solved the problem, please consider posting the solution as an answer rather than a comment. That way, other users will be able to see in search results that your question has an answer. It's absolutely fine to post an answer to your own question, see [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` to the Json.net serializer option did the trick for me.

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comment, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
             NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
```

Another potential solution could be splitting the C# classes and then inherit from a base class, though i haven't tried it enough.

```
    public class Content
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")] public string Type { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class TextContent : Content
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")] public string? Text { get; set; }
    }
```